# Php7 with couchbase sdk2 return a warning when try to insert values in couchbase

Tags: php, couchbase, php-7

I compiled the library couchbase for php7: https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase/tree/php7. 
When I try to make an operation(upsert) I have an error.

```
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('127.0.0.1', "user", "password");
$db = $cluster->openBucket('default');
$db->upsert('testdoc', ['name' =>'Frank']);

PHP Warning:  Invalid callback , no array or string given in Unknown on line 0
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. CouchbaseBucket->upsert() php shell code:1
PHP   3. _CouchbaseBucket->upsert() [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php:134
PHP Warning:  Invalid callback , no array or string given in Unknown on line 0
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. CouchbaseBucket->upsert() php shell code:1
PHP   3. _CouchbaseBucket->upsert() [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php:134
```

If I try

```
$db->upsert('testdoc', 'Frank');
```

or

```
$db->upsert('testdoc', json_encode(['key' => 'Frank']) );
```

Generate the same warning and insert in couchbase for that key(testdoc) an empty string. How can fix this error?

Comment: Which OS/architecture and which specific PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That branch is still under development and is effectively a port of the extension, since the APIs for extension developers has changed so much.  We have it partially done, working on some platforms, but with enough known issues that it's not released yet.  It'd be helpful to let us know what OS/architecture and specific PHP version you're using so I can verify our test coverage says the same thing-- then it's just a known issue.

Comment: The php version is: PHP 7.0.4-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) ( NTS )
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, the S.O. is: DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rebecca
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

Comment: Thanks for that.  Note that we have some new commits there on the branch as of the last day or so.  Can you try the latest?

Comment: I dont' see new commits https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase/commits/php7 or https://github.com/brett19/php-couchbase/commits/php7. Exists another repo with this extension?

Comment: It's currently in code review and it looks like we're far enough along to merge back into master.  As of this writing, this would be the best thing to pull: http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/62338/.  The whole list is here: http://review.couchbase.org/#/q/project:php-couchbase

Comment: After the lasts commits the extension is working. Thanks.